Solving integral of $\frac{\sin^n(ax)}{\cos^m(ax)}$ from wiki
I was looking at the wiki of trig integrals since wolfram alpha was not being helpful at all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_both_sine_and_cosine
And it seems that when looking at this:
$$\displaystyle \int {\frac {\sin ^{n}ax\,dx}{\cos ^{m}ax}}=\begin{cases}{\displaystyle\frac {\sin ^{n+1}ax}{a(m-1)\cos ^{m-1}ax}}-\displaystyle{\frac {n-m+2}{m-1}}\int {\frac {\sin ^{n}ax\,dx}{\cos ^{m-2}ax}}&{\mbox{(for }}m\neq 1{\mbox{)}}\\\displaystyle {\frac {\sin ^{n-1}ax}{a(m-1)\cos ^{m-1}ax}}-{\frac {n-1}{m-1}}\int {\frac {\sin ^{n-2}ax\,dx}{\cos ^{m-2}ax}}&{\mbox{(for }}m\neq 1{\mbox{)}}\\\displaystyle-{\frac {\sin ^{n-1}ax}{a(n-m)\cos ^{m-1}ax}}+{\frac {n-1}{n-m}}\int {\frac {\sin ^{n-2}ax\,dx}{\cos ^{m}ax}}&{\mbox{(for }}m\neq n{\mbox{)}}\end{cases}$$
Which is the one I am looking to solve for $n,m = 3$, however, I am confused about which I should use from the piecewise solution.
It says for the top 2 when $m\neq 1$ but it does not make sense to me which of the 2 I should use.

But when looking at again at the wiki for the next trig integral (as a comparison) with cosine on top and sine on the bottom the $n,m$ conditions are not consistent.
$$\displaystyle \int {\frac {\cos ^{n}ax\,dx}{\sin ^{m}ax}}={\begin{cases}\displaystyle-{\frac {\cos ^{n+1}ax}{a(m-1)\sin ^{m-1}ax}}\displaystyle-{\frac {n-m+2}{m-1}}\int {\frac {\cos ^{n}ax\,dx}{\sin ^{m-2}ax}}&{\mbox{(for }}n\neq 1{\mbox{)}}\\\displaystyle-{\frac {\cos ^{n-1}ax}{a(m-1)\sin ^{m-1}ax}}-{\frac {n-1}{m-1}}\int {\frac {\cos ^{n-2}ax\,dx}{\sin ^{m-2}ax}}&{\mbox{(for }}m\neq 1{\mbox{)}}\\ \displaystyle{\frac {\cos ^{n-1}ax}{a(n-m)\sin ^{m-1}ax}}+{\frac {n-1}{n-m}}\int {\frac {\cos ^{n-2}ax\,dx}{\sin ^{m}ax}}&{\mbox{(for }}m\neq n{\mbox{)}}\end{cases}}$$
I think this could be a mistake/typo on the wiki, but I am not sure.
Even though the solutions are very similar, the top solution from both are inconsistent?

Please help me to find the right solution for
$$\int \frac{\sin^3(ax)}{\cos^3(ax)}dx = ?$$

Btw on Wikipedia you can right click the LaTeX and click "open in new tab". You may notice that the title of that tab is the LaTeX code. To access it, you can create a bookmark which will automatically default to be named the title of the tab which you can copy and delete the bookmark. Alternatively, you can click "inspect" instead of "open in new tab" and get the data from there.

Presumably both of the first two identities work, but the second option reduces the power of both numerator and denominator and so is probably more efficient. In that case, for $m = n \geq 2$, the identity specializes to a reduction identity for $\int \tan^m ax ,dx$.

Related (but not a duplicate): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220369/expressing-int-tann-x-dx-with-a-sum

If your main objective is to find that integral, then
$$\int \tan^3(ax) dx\\ =\int \tan (ax)\big(\sec^2(ax)-1\big) dx$$
Separate the integrals, and solve, it's very easy.

Now if I assign $x = \sqrt{z^2+y^2}$, will this change the answer significantly where I need to integrate over $z$ and $y$?
I am unsure if wolfram is doing it correctly here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+tan%5E3%28ax%29+dx if I want to assign $x = \sqrt{z^2+y^2}$.

And in general, will substituting $x$ for any other expression after you have done the integral be correct?

Regarding your question, I would take the middle case, as that in your case with $n=m=3$ would leave you with needing to find the indefinite integral of $\tan (ax)$.
As for the correctness of the formulas... well, one way is to take the derivate of the righthand side and see if that is the same as the integrand on the lefthand side. I suspect a lot of trigonometric algebra would be needed through. I am not sure I see where the inconsistency is.
